# CSS problem with a class

Tags: html, css

Can you help me to set the text color of the class `slide` anchors? Here in http://jsfiddle.net/x7zpd/ is my problem shown.

```
<div id="menu-demo">

        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="up">
                    <a href="#">INICIO</a></div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a href="#">INICIO</a></div>
            </li>
```

```
#menu-demo li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#aaa;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;    
}
.up {
    margin-top:13px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
 .slide
{
    background-color: #ffc; /* delete me */
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

#menu-demo li .slide a
   {
       background-color: #ffc; /* delete me */
       color: black;
   }

... otherwise the normal `a` will have priority, since it's more internal and IDs + hierarchy have priority on classes.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor tag has a color assigned to it as well that overrides the color of the parent container. You also need a .slide A{color:#000;} in there as well.